# NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager

Tags: android, shared-libraries, noclassdeffounderror

i read a lot of topic about this error : E/AndroidRuntime(16097): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager

i just link facebook sdk to my project, compil is ok, but with the following code i got the error

here is my Java Build Path : https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzqO5.png

```
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

      // callback when session changes state
      @Override
      public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened()) {

          // make request to the /me API
          Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            // callback after Graph API response with user object
          });
        }
      }
    });
```

thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have `android-support-v4.jar` or `android-support-v13.jar` in `libs/` of your project?

Comment: Yes i have android-support-v4.jar

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This problem was hounding me for almost Six months now and no solution was helping me but today I have managed to find the correct solution on my own.

When you select you project target version to be more than or equal to Android 4.0 Android SDK includes "android-support-v4.jar" file in your projects "libs" folder.This jar contains all the classes and methods related Android 4.0 or later

You can see your problem, android is trying to find the class definition which is in "android-support-v4.jar" so that means you have not configured the build path to the "android-support-v4.jar" file.To do this follow these steps:

1.Open your project properties 
2.Select "Java Build Path" from left side menu 
3.Select "Libraries" tab 
4.Press "Add External Jar"
5.MOST IMPORTANT STEPS :-
Select "android-support-v4" jar file of "libs" folder of YOUR CURRENT  PROJECT LOCATION(Path Should be of your project only and not the android sdk). 
6.Select "Order and Export" tab and "TICK" the checkbox of "android-support-v4.jar"

That's it, your done !!

Comment: thanks rauf .. this is the best solution, saved a lot of time,

Answer (score 9):

Don't add jar files in Build-path follow these steps

Remove all jar files from java build path and follow these steps

You should try this:

1. Remove all references to the JAR in your project from Java

> project -> properties -> Java build path -> libraries

1. Create a **libs** folder if not exist at the root of your project Copy the JAR into the libs folder.
2. If still not running OK. **Right click your project > Android Tools > Fix Project Properties**

clean your project and run. it will work

Comment: tyvm, i did all the step but le #3 doesn't work i have now error of compilation : import com.google.gson.Gson;

look at my files : http://img837.imageshack.us/img837/3245/t901.png

Comment: when i remove the facebook reference everything is ok : http://img90.imageshack.us/img90/6048/pnbq.png

Comment: ok it was a miss match between my two android-support-v4.jar, thx a lot for your help.